# Is my proof correct - $[0, 1] \times \{0\} \times \dots \times \{0\}$ is zero measure

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure

I'm trying to prove that  $A = [0, 1] \times \{0\} \times \dots \times \{0\}$ is zero measure in $\mathbb R^d$. We perform the $\times$ operation $d-1$ times.

What I did:

Let $\epsilon >0 $.

Consider the cubes $C_1 = [0, \sqrt[d]{\epsilon}] \times [0, \sqrt[d]{\epsilon}] \times \dots [0, \sqrt[d]{\epsilon}]$ and $C_2 = [\sqrt[d]{\epsilon}, 2\sqrt[d]{\epsilon}] \times [0, \sqrt[d]{\epsilon}] \times \dots \times [0, \sqrt[d]{\epsilon}]$ until the final cube $C_n = [(n-1)\sqrt[d]{\epsilon}, n\sqrt[d]{\epsilon}] \times [0, \sqrt[d]{\epsilon}] \times \dots \times [0, \sqrt[d]{\epsilon}]$ where $n\sqrt[d]{\epsilon} > 1$.

We have that $A \subset \cup_{i=1}^{n}C_i$, but $\sum_{i=1}^{n}V(C_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \epsilon = n\epsilon < (n+1) \epsilon$

Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrarily small and $n$ is constant, $\epsilon^* = (n + 1)\epsilon$ is also arbitrarily small, so overall we have that

$A \subset \cup_{i=1}^{n}C_i$, but $\sum_{i=1}^{n}V(C_i) < \epsilon^*$ for all $\epsilon ^* > 0$, thus $A$ is zero measure.

Is this correct and rigorous enough?

Comment: There is a slight flaw. Your $n$ is not constant but it depends on $\epsilon$.

Comment: Which means that $(n+1) \epsilon$ is not arbitrarily small...

Comment: Just add another assumption on $n$, like $n(\epsilon)^{\frac{1}{d}}<2$ and you can repair your proof. But I would stick to 5xum answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect, because you claim $n$ is constant, but in fact it depends on the choice of $\epsilon$.

It can be even simpler. You don't need $n$ sets to cover $A$, because you don't need *cubes*, you just need *boxes*.

---

For each $\epsilon$, you can define $$C_\epsilon = [0,1]\times [0,\sqrt[d-1]{\epsilon}]\times [0,\sqrt[d-1]{\epsilon}]\times\cdots\times [0,\sqrt[d-1]{\epsilon}]$$

and you have $A\subseteq C_\epsilon$ and $V(C_\epsilon) = 1\cdot \sqrt[d-1]{\epsilon}\cdot \sqrt[d-1]{\epsilon}\cdots\sqrt[d-1]{\epsilon}=\epsilon$

Comment: I'm a bit torn about it. Shouldn't it be an infinite union of open cubes? In both our proofs it is a finite union of closed cubes (meaning a cube should be product of open intervals, not closed ones)

Comment: @RickJoker You can always add infinitely many empty sets to the end and stil get the same union.

Comment: @RickJoker It would help if you wrote down what definition of "measure $0$" you are working with.